# Get access to a variable in a class without copying it

Tags: c++, getter-setter

I would like to get access to fields from a class without copying it.

I have a class that stores two variables (simplified version here).
In the `get_cutting_types` method I check where the user inputs `true` or `false` and pass the object back by reference. But here I have to use `=`, meaning the data is copied.

Is there a direct way to pass a field without re-assignment?

```
class joint
{
    std::vector<char> m_letters;
    std::vector<char> f_letters;

    void get_cutting_types(bool flag, std::vector<char>& letters) {
        if (flag) {
            letters= m_letters;
        } else {
            letters= f_letters;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a timber joint...

Comment: In this case I believe it is. Isnt it?

Comment: @alterigel I don't have access to the actual ISO C++ spec :(

Comment: `get_cutting_types` should return `std::vector<char>&`, that is, a reference to either `m_boolean_type` or `f_boolean_type`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, so actually by writing "=" there is no copy?

Comment: `bool male_or_female` is a terrible name... Looking at the name only, `true` would mean that it's a male or female and not some of the other options. Looking at how you use it, I suggest that you make it `bool male;` instead. Edit: `flag` doesn't say more than `male_or_female`. It's equally bad.

Comment: @Petras -- there is no copy when you create a reference. That's what references are about: refering to some other object.

Comment: @PeteBecker, thanks you remark answers my question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo an `enum class TimberJoint { MALE, FEMALE }` would work much better.

Comment: @Dai Yes, that would be even better but that'd be an ABI breaking change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, but:

- I don't think you're going to be able to avoid using an "=" sign somwhere along the way.  And I don't see any reason that's a problem.
- If all you want is to return a boolean value: then maybe just add a new public method to your class, e.g.

  ```
  public:
    bool isMale() { return <<some test>>; } // Easy peasy!
  ```

Q: Does this address your concern(s)?

Q: Or do you need "something else"?  If so, please clarify.

---

> Sorry maybe there was confusion in the code of variable naming. It is
> only a return values of char not a single boolean flag.

OK, maybe you want something like this:

```
public:
    const std::vector<char>& get_cutting_types(bool is_male) {
      return (is_male) ? m_letters : f_letters; 
    }
```

Comment: Sorry maybe there was confusion in the code of variable naming. It is only a return values of char not a single boolean flag.

Comment: Ah, I forgot it is possible to return value by reference... thank you

Comment: is there any reason why it is const? Just not to change the initial value?

Comment: @Petras That depends on whether or not callers of `get_cutting_types` should be able to mutate the vector or not. I would argue they should not (so the return-type should be `const vector<char>&`) because `get_cutting_types` returns a reference to an object **owned** by `class joint`. My opinion is only the _exclusive owner_ of an object should be able to mutate it, all other objects should only have read-only views of data they don't own. That said, **add inline documentation** to make it clear.